# If $p$ is a prime other than 2 or 5, prove that $p$ must be one of the forms $10k + 1$, $10k + 3$, $10k + 7$, or $10k + 9$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

If $p$ is a prime other than 2 or 5, prove that $p$ must be one of the forms $10k + 1$, $10k + 3$, $10k + 7$, or $10k + 9$

-The section we are covering is on the division algorithm, although I am unsure as to how to utilize it in this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: If we write out a prime number that is greater than $5$ in decimal, what are the possibilities for the last digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every number is of the form $10k, 10k+1$, $10k+2, 10k+3, \ldots ,10k+9$. If $p$ is prime this eliminates $10k+2, 10k+4, 10k+6, 10k+8$ since they are divisible by $2$, and $10k+5$ since it is divisible by $5$. And $10k$ is divisible by $10$.

To see the divisibility factorise them, for example $10k+4=2(5k+2)$.

Comment: Let's not forget about multiples of $10$ !

Answer (score 0):

So you wish to express $10k + c$ as $bq + r$ with $0 \leq r < b$. If $r = 0$ and $10k + c \neq b$, that means $10k + c$ and $b$ share a common prime factor, and if $b$ is the prime then $10k + c$ is composite.

Try it with $b = 2$, which you know is a prime number. Then:

- $10k + 0 = 2(5k) + 0$
- $10k + 2 = 2(5k + 1) + 0$
- $10k + 4 = 2(5k + 2) + 0$
- $10k + 6 = 2(5k + 3) + 0$
- $10k + 8 = 2(5k + 4) + 0$

Since $r = 0$ in each of these cases and we know 2 is prime, this must mean that these $10k + c$ are composite.

Very similarly you take care of $10k + 5$ with $b = 5$.

This leaves only $10k + 1$, $10k + 3$, $10k + 7$ and $10k + 9$ as potentially prime.